# p:inputTextarea characters remaining ignores enter

Tags: primefaces

I am using `p:inputTextarea` characters remaining, but when counting the characters, it ignores the ENTER key.

This is my code:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="txtObsrId" style="width:700px" value="#{xx}" 
    disabled="#{xx}" maxlength="4000" autoResize="false"
    counterTemplate="{0} caracteres restantes." counter="display2">
    <f:validateLength maximum="4000" />
    </p:inputTextarea>

<h:outputText id="display2" />
```

Comment: Which Primefaces Version?

Comment: Improved the grammar and a typo. I think it needs more work though (I'm not familiar with intputTextarea/primefaces/etc)